# Querying editable user calendars returns non-editable calendars

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When querying editable user calendars, i.e. using the `canEdit+eq+true` OData filter clause, I am receiving the non-editable calendars instead.

Here down the REST query endpoint (`{userId}` replaced with any existing user GUID):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/calendars?$filter=canEdit+eq+true
```

and here is the response result:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{userId}')/calendars",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "some-id",
            "name": "Jours fériés - France",
            "canEdit": false,
        },
        {
            "id": "some-other-id",
            "name": "Anniversaires",
            "canEdit": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

When querying the reverse property, i.e. the non-editable calendars, I receive the editable calendars as response payload:

Here down the REST query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/calendars?$filter=canEdit+eq+false
```

And below is the response result:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{userId}')/calendars",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "some-id",
            "name": "Calendar",
            "canEdit": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that I omitted irrelevant fields from both response results.

Is there a know issue or am I mis-understating the `canEdit` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's known issue according [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2710).

Workaround can be to retrieve the editable calendars by using the `canEdit eq false`.

But I'm little bit affraid of it.